# How to add a checkbox to D3 nodes?

Tags: javascript, d3.js, twitter-bootstrap-3

I would like to know if it is possible to add a checkbox to the top-left corner of each rect in the D3 Zoomable Icicle layout example (http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/1005873)?

If this is possible, can anyone possibly assist with example code to achieve this?

Comment: You would need to, instead of appending the `rect` elements directly, append `g` elements first and then the `rect` elements underneath. Then you can add `foreignObject`s with checkboxes to the same `g` elements.

Comment: Hi @LarsKotthoff, do you know how I can achieve this, I haven't had any luck getting it to work...

Comment: Can you post what you've done so far and what you're struggling with please?

Comment: Hi Lars, I managed to get it working in the mean time - can you perhaps have a look at this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25487249/how-to-remove-foreignobject-from-rect-on-toggle-in-d3 Thanks!!

Comment: Hi @Lars, for some reason when I select the checkboxes they won't tick i.e. show the arrow...have you come across something like this before?