# How to remove foreignobject from rect on toggle in D3

Tags: javascript, jquery, d3.js

I can successfully add a checkbox using foreignobject on a rect in D3:

```
rect = svg.selectAll("g.rect.Rect").data(nodes, keyFunction);
...
rect
    .append("foreignObject")
    .filter(function (d) { return d.children || d.fileType == "File folder"; })
    .attr("class", "Rect")
    .on("mouseover", mouseover)
    .on("click", nameClicked)
    .attr("width", 20)
    .attr("height", 20)
    .attr("transform", function (d) {
        return "translate(" + [(x(d.x)), (y(d.y))] + ")" + "scale(1)";
     })         
    .append("xhtml:rect")
    .html("<input type=checkbox id=check />")
    .on("click", function(d, i){
        console.log(svg.select("#check").node().checked);
    });
```

What I need to do is toggle the checkbox on and off on button click:

```
function LinkToggle()
{
    //do something here to remove / hide checkbox / foreignobject
}
```

If anyone can help me with this, it will be much appreciated as I don't know how to go about it :(

Thanks!

Comment: Even though this was marked as a duplicate, I would like to thank you for the link as that helped for a toggle, and I wouldn't have found the link to the answer otherwise!

Comment: Hi @Lars, for some reason when I select the checkboxes they won't tick i.e. show the arrow...have you come across something like this before?

Comment: Did you check that you're selecting the thing you want to select and that the `checked` property changes? You may want to ask a separate question about this with complete code.

Comment: Hi @LarsKotthoff, I have asked another question regarding this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25585409/checkbox-in-d3-not-responding-properly