# Checkbox in D3 not responding properly

Tags: javascript, checkbox, d3.js

I am making use of a foreign object to add a checkbox to each element in my data that is displayed using D3 using this code:

```
rect.append("g")
    .append("foreignObject")
    .filter(function (d) { return d.children || d.fileType == "File folder"; })
    .attr("class", "Rect")
    .on("mouseover", mouseover)
        .on("click", nameClicked)
        .attr("width", 20)
        .attr("height", 20)
        .attr("transform", function (d) {
             return "translate(" + [(x(d.x)), (y(d.y))] + ")" + "scale(1)";
         })
        .append("xhtml:rect")
        .html("<input type=checkbox id=check />")
        .on("click", function(d, i){
            console.log("clicked check"+ svg.select("#check").node().checked);  
           if(svg.select("#check").node().checked)
            {
                copyClick.push(d);
                svgCopy.push(svg);
            }           
        });
```

But I have two problems:

1. Sometimes the checkbox is not selectable - if you click on it it doesn't always show the tick mark;
2. If I select a node in the graph, the root is also selected.

[image]

I'm not sure if anyone could help with these issues?

**Edit:**

I have now concluded that the problem is not with the rect, but with the leaves:

```
var leaves = svg.selectAll(".leaves").data(nodes, keyFunction).enter().append("g")
            .filter(function (d, i) {
                return !d.children && d.fileType != "File folder"  && d.dx >0.01;
            }).attr("class", "leaves")
            .attr("transform", function (d) { 
                return "translate(" + [(x(d.x)), (y(d.y))] + ")" + "scale(1)";
            })
            .on("mouseover", mouseover)
            .on("click", nameClicked);

leaves.append("image")
        .attr("xlink:href", function (d) {
            if (d.fT == "Document")
                return "images/document512d.png";
            if (d.fT == "Music")
                return "images/music/music2-256m.png";
            if (d.fT == "Picture")
                return "images/pictures/image2-256i.png";
            if (d.fT == "Video")
                return "images/video/play-256p.png";
            if (d.fT == "Other")
                return "images/other/other.png";
            return "images/other/other.png";

        })
        .attr("height", function (d) { /*console.log("y(d.dy): " + y(d.dy));*/return y(d.dy); })
        .attr("title", function (d) {
            return "";
        });

leaves.append('rect')
        .attr('class', 'image-border')
        .attr('width', function (d) { console.log(d); console.log("image-border: "+d.dx);return x(d.dx); })
        .attr('height', function (d) { console.log("image-border: "+d.dy); return y(d.dy); });

leaves.attr("class", "leaves").append("foreignObject")
        .style("margin-left","0px")
        .attr("width", 10)
        .attr("height", 20)
        .attr("transform", function (d) {
                return "translate(" + [((d.x)), ((d.y))] + ")" + "scale(1)";
            })
        .append("xhtml:div")
        .html("<input type=checkbox id=check />")
        .on("click", function(d, i){
            console.log(svg.select("#check").node().checked);
        });
```

Comment: Could you provide a complete example that demonstrates the problem please?

Comment: Hi @LarsKotthoff, how would I get the checkbox of a specific d?

Comment: If the checkbox element itself has the ID, then just the usual `d3.select("#id")`.

Comment: Hi @LarsKotthoff, I am not able to provide an example at the moment as this is part of a much bigger application, but I have provided more code - when I click the checkbox of a rect it works properly (when it allows to be selected), but when I select one of the leaves, it checks the root rect as well.

Comment: Is it possible that when you click the checkbox the handler for the `g` element fires as well and causes this?

Comment: I think that's the problem, was just looking at that now...not sure how to fix that :/

Comment: I think I found it with your help @LarsKotthoff! Instead of saying svg.select("#check") I should use d3.select("#check")! But, I still have the problem sometimes of the checkbox not wanting to check, when you mouseover you can see it's enabled but no arrow shows...

Comment: You'll really have to provide a reproducible example for more help...

Comment: Nope still not working - if I log `d3.select("#check").node().checked`, it's always false even if an item is checked. But if I say `if(d3.select("#check").node().checked) d3.select("#check").node().checked = null;
else d3.select("#check").node().checked = true;` then it toggles each subsequent checkbox on or off....although the arrows are working properly. How would I get it to check on and off for the checkbox selected?